# this javascript pop up box for edit images works in firefox and chrome but not shows pop up box in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

```
$('#rm-css-launch').removeClass('disabled').attr('href', '#launch-css').bind('click',                function (event) {
$(event.currentTarget).siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
        RMUIWidgetRelay.relayEvent(RMUIEvent.EDITOR_MODE_CHANGE, 'css');
        alert("Test");
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Duplicate of [javacript not working in IE which works fine in firefox and mozila](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9562027/javacript-not-working-in-ie-which-works-fine-in-firefox-and-mozila) - OK, your first attempt to ask this was closed, but your second attempt at this question is still open so please go back to that one and provide more details - you didn't need to post it a third time.

Comment: @ You know the exact Reason For This ?

Comment: I don't know how to edit

Comment: Look just above these comments, to the bottom left of the main part of your question just under the JavaScript, jQuery, etc tags. There is an "edit" link.

Comment: but what is wrong in this question ?

Answer (score 1):

Read the comments in the code below.

```
$('#rm-css-launch').removeClass('disabled')
  .attr('href', '#launch-css')
  .bind('click', function(event){
    //IE7 & IE8 do not support the method 'event.currentTarget';
    //use 'this' instead.
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active').end().addClass('active');
    RMUIWidgetRelay.relayEvent(RMUIEvent.EDITOR_MODE_CHANGE, 'css');
    alert("Test");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy This is Working Fine in IE